# Characterization of convex functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

From now on $I$ will always denote an **open** interval of $\mathbb{R}$

Let $f \; : \; I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, $f$ is said to be convex iff

$$f((1-\gamma)x + \gamma y) \leq (1 - \gamma)f(x) + \gamma f(y) \hspace{0.4cm} \forall x,y \in I \; , \; \forall \gamma \in ]0,1[$$

A well known criterion for convexity is the following

**First criterion of convexity**
If $f \; I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that
$$(A1)\;\;f'(x) \text{ exists } \;\; \forall x \in I$$
$$(A2)\;\;f'(x) \leq f'(y) \hspace{0.3cm} \forall x,y \in I \; : \; x \leq y$$

Then $f$ is convex

The criterion gives a sufficient condition which is not necessary, the example $f(x) = |x|$ shows that. I tried to generalize the criterion to find a condition which is sufficient and necessary for the convexity, this is what I managed to do.

Let $f$ be a convex function, it can be proved that the function

$$\begin{split} \Phi \; : \; (I \times I) \setminus \Delta &\to \mathbb{R} \\
(x,y) &\mapsto \Phi(x,y) = \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \end{split}$$

where $(I \times I) \setminus \Delta = \{ (x,y) \in I \times I \; : \; x \neq y\}$

is increasing both in $x$ and in $y$.

From this property it's pretty easy to show that

$$(B1) \; f'^-(x) \text{ and } f'^+(x) \hspace{0.4cm} \text{ both exists and are finite} \hspace{0.3cm} \forall x \in I$$
$$(B2) \; f'^-(x) \leq f'^+(x) \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x \in I$$
$$(B3) \; f'^+(x) \leq f'^-(y) \hspace{0.5cm} \forall x,y \in I \; : \; x < y$$

where $f'^-(x) := \lim_{y \to x^-}{\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}}$ , $f'^+(x) := \lim_{y \to x^+}{\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}}$

now let $D := \{ x \in I \; \text{ such that $f'(x)$ doesn't exist} \}$, in other words $D$ is the set of the point of non differentiability of $f$
from the properties stated above it's easy to see that

$D \subseteq \{ \text{ discontinuity points of $f'^-$} \}$

and because $f'^-$ is increasing ( what I mean with "increasing" is what some people mean with "non-decreasing" ) the discontinuity points of $f'^-$ are at most countable, therefore the point of non derivability of $f$ are at most countable, therefore $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable

So although $f$ isn't necessarily everywhere differentiable it is *almost* everywhere differentiable

**Generalized first criterion of convexity**
Let $f \; : \; I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, if $f$ is convex if then (B1),(B2) and (B3) holds. furthermore the non differentiable points of $f$ are at most countable.

My question is, are the condition $(B1),(B2)$ and $(B3)$ also **sufficient** for the convexity of $f$ ?
If so, how can I prove it? If they're not, what is a counterexample?

There is also another criterion of convexity

**Second criterion of convexity** if $f \; : \; I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that
$$(C1) f''(x) \;\; \text{ exists } \forall x \in I$$
$$(C2) f''(x) \geq 0 \;\; \forall x \in I$$
then $f$ is convex

Can the **Second criterion of convexity** be generalized in a similar way to the first? Is there a result about the maximum cardinality of the points where $f$ isn't twice differentabile ? (similar to the result "the points where $f$ isn't differentiable are at most countable")

Comment: Have you checked Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*? There are a lot of results on one-sided derivatives etc.

Comment: Some thoughts (it is not appropriate as an answer): Let $I$ be an interval. Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Then $f$ is convex on $I$ if and only if
$$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \le \frac{f(z) - f(y)}{z - y} \tag{1}$$
for all $x < y < z$ in $I$.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to prove the condition stated by [River Li](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/584414/river-li). This proves that the **Generalized first criterion of convexity** $\implies$ **convexity**

to prove I use this generalized version of the [Fermat's stationary point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Fermat%27s%20theorem%20(also,is%20zero%20at%20that%20point))

**Generalized Fermat's stationary point theorem**
Let $g \; [0,1] \; \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, let $\gamma_0 \in ]0,1[$ then

if $\gamma_0$ is a local minimum point and if both $g'^-(\gamma_0)$ and $g'^+(\gamma_0)$ exists, then $g'^-(\gamma_0) \leq 0 \leq g'^+(\gamma_0)$

if $\gamma_0$ is a local maximum point and if both $g'^-(\gamma_0)$ and $g'^+(\gamma_0)$ exists, then $g'^+(\gamma_0) \leq 0 \leq g'^-(\gamma_0)$

The proof of the **Generalized Fermat's stationary point theorem** is not very different from the proof of the Standard [Fermat's stationary point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Fermat%27s%20theorem%20(also,is%20zero%20at%20that%20point))

Now to prove the statement I first prove a very useful Lemma

**Lemma**
Let $f \; : \; I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that (B1),(B2) and (B3) holds, then

$$f'^+(x) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq f'^-(y)$$

forall $x < y$ in $I$

**Proof of the Lemma**

Let $x,y \in I$ such that $x < y$

Let $g \; : \; [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined in this way

$$g(\gamma) := f(x) + \gamma(f(y) - f(x)) - f((1-\gamma)x + \gamma y)$$

I know that $g(0) = g(1) = 0$, also $g$ is continuos because $f$ is continuos ($f$ is continuos because the existence of $f'^+$ and $f'^-$ implies the continuity).
It's quite easy to show that for all $\gamma \in ]0,1[$ $g'^+(\gamma$) and $g'^-(\gamma)$ both exists and

$$g'^-(\gamma) = f(y) - f(x) - f'^-((1-\gamma)x + \gamma y)(y - x)$$
$$g'^+(\gamma) = f(y) - f(x) - f'^+((1-\gamma)x + \gamma y)(y - x)$$

It's clear $g$ either has an internal maximum point or an internal minimum point.

**Maximum point case** let's assume that $g$ has an internal maximum point, let's call this point $\gamma_0$, then thanks to the **Generalized Fermat's stationary point theorem** I know that

$$g'^+(\gamma_0) \leq 0 \leq g'^-(\gamma_0)$$

meaning

$$f(y) - f(x) - f'^+((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)(y - x) \leq 0$$
$$0 \leq f(y) - f(x) - f'^-((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)(y - x)$$

manipulating these inequalities gives

$$f'^-((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq f'^+((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)$$

and using (B2) I get

$$f'^+(x) \leq  f'^-((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq f'^+((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)\leq f'^-(y)$$

So in particular

$$\label{disuguaglianza} f'^+(x) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq f'^-(y)$$

**Minimum point case** let's assume that $g$ has an internal minimum point, let's call this point $\gamma_0$, then thanks to the **Generalized Fermat's stationary point theorem** I know that

$$g'^-(\gamma_0) \leq 0 \leq g'^+(\gamma_0)$$

meaning

$$f(y) - f(x) - f'^-((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)(y - x) \leq 0$$
$$0 \leq f(y) - f(x) - f'^+((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)(y - x)$$

manipulating these inequalities gives

$$f'^+((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq f'^-((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)$$

but because of $(B2)$ I have that

$$f'^+((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y) = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} = f'^-((1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0 y)$$

and $f$ is differentiable in $(1-\gamma_0)x + \gamma_0y$, in any case using (B3) i have once again

$$f'^+(x) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} \leq f'^-(y)$$

which completes the proof of the **Lemma**

Now let's dive into the real proof.

Let $f \; : \; I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $(B1),(B2)$ and $(B3)$ holds, then $f$ is convex

**Proof***

As I said I will prove the condition stated by [River Li](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/584414/river-li), i.e.

$$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \leq \frac{f(c) - f(b)}{c - b}$$

for all $a < b < c$ in $I$

By using the lemma first with $x = a, y =b$ and then with $x = b , y = c$ and using (B2) and (B3) I get

$$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \leq f'^-(b) \leq f'^+(b) \leq \frac{f(c) - f(b)}{c - b}$$

which proves

$$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} \leq  \frac{f(c) - f(b)}{c - b}$$

which proves the convexity of $f$.

Therefore the following the **Generalized first criterion of convexity** is also a **sufficient** condition for the convexity, therefore the condition (B1),(B2) and (B3) are a complete characterization of the convexity.

Another question still remains, is there a **Generalized second criterion of convexity** ?